# Removing shapes from modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

My code is supposed to remove the drawings after selecting "3", but for some reason is not deleting them. It is not giving me any errors, it's just not deleting them. When I define my circle and rectangle module on my main module, it works perfectly, but when I create separate modules and want to delete the shapes, it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

main module:

```
import random
from rectangle import *
from circle import *

# Create a turtle object
myturtle = turtle.Turtle()

def remove():
    myturtle.clear()

def shapes():
    myturtle.pensize(1)
    myturtle.penup()
    myturtle.goto(x.random, yCoordinate.random)
    myturtle.pendown()
    myturtle.color(random)
    myturtle.circle(radius.random)


COMMANDS = [exit, circle, rectangle, remove, shapes, exit]
ABORT = len(COMMANDS) - 1
PROMPT = "1. Draw a circle\n2. Draw a rectangle\n3. Remove Shapes\n4. Draw Shapes\n5. Quit"
COLORS = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue',  'green']

while True:
    choice = turtle.numinput("Pick a number", prompt=PROMPT, default=ABORT, minval=0, maxval=ABORT)
    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        x = int(input("Enter the X Coordinate: "))
        yCoordinate = int(input("Enter the Y Coordinate: "))
        radius = int(input("Enter the Radius: "))
        color = str(input("Enter desired Color (choose red, yellow, blue or green): "))
        xCoordinate = (x - radius)
        circle(x, yCoordinate, radius, color)

    elif choice == 2:
        xRectangle = int(input("Enter the X Coordinate: "))
        yRectangle = int(input("Enter the Y Coordinate: "))
        height = int(input("Enter Height: "))
        width = int(input("Enter Width: "))
        colorRectangle = str(input("Enter desired Color (choose red, yellow, blue or green):  "))
        rectangle(xRectangle, yRectangle, width, height, colorRectangle)

    elif choice == 3:
        COMMANDS[choice]()

    elif choice == 4:
        #Here you can adjust the lower and upper bounds of the random number
        x, yCoordinate, color, radius = random.randint(10,40), random.randint(10,200), random.choice(COLORS), random.randint(10,200)
        COMMANDS[1](x, yCoordinate, radius,color)
        print("Drew a circle")
        xRectangle, yRectangle, width, height, colorRectangle = random.randint(10,200), random.randint(10,200), random.randint(10,200),random.randint(10,200), random.choice(COLORS)
        COMMANDS[2](xRectangle, yRectangle, width, height, colorRectangle)
        print("Drew a rectangle")

    elif choice == 5:
        COMMANDS[choice]()

    else:
        print("Invalid, try again...")
        continue
```

circle.py

```
import turtle

myturtle = turtle.Turtle()

def circle(x, yCoordinate, radius, color):
    myturtle.pensize(1)
    myturtle.penup()
    myturtle.goto(x, yCoordinate)
    myturtle.pendown()
    myturtle.pencolor(color)
    myturtle.circle(radius)
    myturtle.hideturtle()
```

rectangle.py

```
import turtle

myturtle = turtle.Turtle()

def rectangle(xRectangle, yRectangle, width, height, colorRectangle):
    myturtle.penup()
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)
    myturtle.pendown()
    myturtle.pencolor(colorRectangle)
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle + height / 2)
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle + width / 2, yRectangle + height / 2)
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle + width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)
    myturtle.hideturtle()
```

Answer (score 0):

`turtle.Turtle()` is not a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and thus each time you call it you're getting back a different instance of `Turtle`. Hence, when you draw a rectangle or circle, you're sending draw instructions to a different `Turtle` object than the one that you're sending the clear instruction to.

A quick fix is to pass in the `myturtle` object to the rectangle and circle modules.